# How to stop and resume a spring batch job

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

Goal : I am using spring batch for data processing and I want to have an option to stop/resume (where it left off).

Issue: I am able to send a stop signal to a running job and it gets stopped successfully. But when I try to send start signal to same job its creating a new instance of the job and starts as a fresh job.

My question is how can we achieve a resume functionality for a stopped job in spring batch.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to run it with the same parameters. Just make sure you haven't marked the job as non-restarted and that you're not using `RunIdIncrementer` or similar to automatically generate unique job parameters.

See for instance, [this example](https://gist.github.com/d4575729e7f57e226f02). After the first run, we have:

```
INFO: Job: [SimpleJob: [name=myJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [STOPPED]
Status is: STOPPED, job execution id 0
  #1 step1 COMPLETED
  #2 step2 STOPPED
```

And after the second:

```
INFO: Job: [SimpleJob: [name=myJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
Status is: COMPLETED, job execution id 1
  #3 step2 COMPLETED
  #4 step3 COMPLETED
```

Note that stopped steps will be re-executed. If you're using chunk-oriented steps, make sure that at least the `ItemReader` implements `ItemStream` (and does it with the correct semantics).

Steps marked with `allowRestartWithComplete` will always be re-run.